# How do I bin my data by multiple conditions? I'm trying to set up data to run a bray curtis similarity matrix

Tags: r, bin

I have data that I'm trying to create sample bins and am not sure the best way to go about it.

For each taxa observed, region, depth, individual count, and habitat feature were recorded

There are 6 regions
I want to bin the depth by 300 meters(up to 3000 m) so 10 depth bins
and there are 11 habitat features

I want the end result to be a table that I can use to create a bray curtis similarity matrix.

I want the output to look like this for example:
(There over 100 different taxa observed and the numbers I have under each represent individual count)

If anyone can help I would tremendously appreciate it!

[image]

Comment: Can't do much without sample data. Please do not post an image of data (or code/errors): it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 2):

This code will create a new variable (`depth_bin`), where the variable `depth_num`will be separated in the levels by 300, like: (0,300], (300,600],...

```
library(dplyr)

your_data_frame %>% 
  mutate(depth_bin = cut(depth_num,seq(0,3000,300)))
```

Comment: This is so helpful! How could I combine this with the group by function? When I tried adding it, it doesn't recognize DepthInMeters, even though it recognizes it in the group by function           
mariana %>% 
  group_by(ScientificName, Locality, Mega.Habitat, DepthInMeters) %>% 
  summarise(total.count = sum(IndividualCount))
  mutate(depth_bin = cut(DepthInMeters,seq(0,6000,300)))